# Rectangular shape with characters inside it placed with a certain width

Tags: c++

I am trying to replicate this:

```
Type the height and width of the rectangle: 10 13

+-------------+
|   w   w   w |
|  w   w   w  |
| w   w   w   |
|w   w   w   w|
|   w   w   w |
|  w   w   w  |
| w   w   w   |
|w   w   w   w|
|   w   w   w |
|  w   w   w  |
+-------------+
```

---

```
Type the height and width of the rectangle: 0 0

+-+
+-+
```

---

```
Type the height and width of the rectangle: 4 1
    
    +-+
    | |
    | |
    | |
    |w|
    +-+
```

I succesfully made a subprogram that printed out the rectangle (though it is messy and there's obvious duplications of code). How can I, in the same subprogram (or maybe in a different one) print out the `'w'` and the empty spaces filled with spaces? The `width` of each '`w'` is 4 spaces. I kind of have an idea. That we do `cout << setfill(' ') << setw(4) << 'w'` and then an `if-statement` that if the `setw` exceeds `<= width` it will do a `'\n'`
However this is my code and I would much appreciate how my code could be improven and how to implement a character with width 4 inside the rectangle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_rectangle (int const width,
              int const height)

{
  cout << '+' << '-';

  for (int i {1}; i < width; ++i)

    {
      cout << '-';
    }

  cout << '+' << endl;

  for (int j {}; j < height; ++j)

    {
      cout << '|' << setw(width + 1) << '|' << endl;
    }

  cout << '+' << '-';

  for (int i {1}; i < width; ++i)
  
    {
      cout << '-';
    }

  cout << '+' << endl;

}

int main()

{
  int width {};
  int height {};

  cout << "Enter the height and width of the rectangle: ";
  cin >> height;
  cin >> width;
  print_rectangle(width,height);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: small refactoring should give you a better chance to do it by yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/3xqxxTWjf

Comment: Who taught you to use curly braces to initialize `int`s? That is ugly. And why use empty braces instead of explicitly specifying zero?

Comment: Agreed, @Jim , but it's become influential. I think it's folk trying to have a one-size fits all initialization rule that they'll find holes in as soon as they start making containers.

Comment: @JimRhodes this is your opinion. This forces default initialization of build in types and it is perfectly fine (not needed here).

Comment: @JimRhodes 

My professor does this instead of typing "int i = 0;" or "int i {0};" so I do it aswell.

Comment: Give the professor what they want, but be aware that `std::vector<int>x{10}` is a vector of one value,10, and not a vector of ten values, 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution for the second part which will print the 'w' and the spaces is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_rectangle (int const width,
              int const height)

{
    int counter=1;
    int remainder= (width+1) % height;
  cout << '+' << '-';

  for (int i = 1; i < width; ++i)

    {
      cout << '-';
    }

  cout << '+' << endl;

  for (int j =0 ; j < height; ++j)

    {
        if(j == 0 || j == height )
      cout << '|' << setw(width + 1) << '|' << endl;
        else
        {
            cout << '|';
            for (int i = 0; i <width ; i++)
            {
                if(counter % remainder == 0)
                    cout<<"w";
                else
                   cout<<" ";

                counter++;
            }

            cout << '|'<<endl;

        }
    }

  cout << '+' << '-';

  for (int i =1 ; i < width; ++i)
  
    {
      cout << '-';
    }

  cout << '+' << endl;

}

int main()

{
  int width =0;
  int height =0;

  cout << "Enter the height and width of the rectangle: ";
  cin >> height;
  cin >> width;
  print_rectangle(width,height);

  return 0;
}
```

I have tested the given input cases on it as well and it gives the right output. What's happening here is that the remainder of height and width+1 gives us a remainder and with the help of that remainder we are going to print w's. A counter is incremented in the loop and whenever that counter is a multiple of that remainder w will be printed otherwise space.

Here is the output of the test case input 4 and 1 [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaUzj.png)

And here is the output of test case input 10 and 13 [image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Please learn split problem to smaller pieces which are a small functions.
Take a look on this:

```cpp
using std::setw;

void print_ending(std::ostream& out, int const width) {
    out << '+' << std::string(width, '-') << '+' << '\n';
}

void print_row(std::ostream& out,
               int const width,
               int const period,
               int offset) {
    out << '|' << std::string(std::min(width, offset), ' ');
    if (offset < width) {
        out << 'w';

        auto remainin_width = width - offset - 1;
        for (int i = remainin_width / period; i > 0; --i) {
            out << setw(period) << 'w';
        }
        out << std::string(remainin_width % period, ' ');
    }
    out << "|\n";
}

void print_rectangle(std::ostream& out,
                     int const width,
                     int const height,
                     int period = 4) {
    print_ending(out, width);
    for (int j{}; j < height; ++j) {
        print_row(out, width, period, (height - j) % period);
    }
    print_ending(out, width);
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dP5v8ved9)